# seleniumRC: Problems with browser starting on OS X

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to start simple selenium test on OSX (just downloaded the latest version of RC), with a python client driver. But the browser can't start (it crashes).

The error which I see in console is

```
    15:33:32.867 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ImageIO requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libJPEG.dylib provides version 0.0.0
15:33:53.620 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for profile to be created!
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.populateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:400)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:372)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:733)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:399)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:370)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:129)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
15:33:53.927 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null
```

Answering your questions

---

I set up profile (disabled almost all warnings)...

I see this error now

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ImageIO requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libJPEG.dylib provides version 0.0.0
16:35:54.245 INFO - Launching Firefox...
```

It became smaller, but looks like to be the same

Comment: Have you tried to run firefox with the given profile. It may tell you if the problem comes from firefox or selenium.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if ImageIO is interfering with the loading of Firefox when it is creating its new Firefox profile on creation.

Try create your own firefox profile and then start Selenium RC with the `-firefoxProfileTemplate` argument

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate </path/to/template/>
```

And see how that goes